# Problems with centering in CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I can't get to center a component perfectly I want this form to be in the middle and that works, but I can't get the background to be around it perfectly, I've tried millions of things can someone give me a hand?
Thank you in advanced.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <title>Accounts</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="authform">
                <form class="my-form form-horizontal">
                    <div class="color">
                        <fieldset>

                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username"></label>  
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <center><input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control input-md a-in" required="" type="text"></center>
                            </div>

                            <br><br><br>

                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <center><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md a-in" required="" type="password"></center>
                            </div>

                            <br><br><br>

                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="send"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button id="send" name="send" class="btn">Auth</button>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.authform {

  padding-top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  float: center;

}
.color {

  margin: auto;
  float: center;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). In my opinion, it's the single best thing that ever happened to CSS.

See my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/NpawYB) for an example using your HTML.

These 3 lines of CSS are the most important:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

**Edit**: My CodePen might not look perfectly centered, but that's because `height: 100vh` doesn't really work in CodePen. But it'll work outside of CodePen.

**Edit 2**: Updated codepen

Comment: It is actualy centering but now the inputs are uncenterd https://ibb.co/eBTdmF that happed when i added .a-in {
  width: 360px;
} because if not the text would be tiny

Comment: I updated the CodePen. It was just a matter of using another FlexBox. Also: Please notice how I simplified the HTML. It lets me think and design clearly. Even for large websites, simple HTML is a great way to go. Also, feel free to use Bootstrap, but I prefer to keep it to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try, in css:

```
text-align:center;
margin-left:(half of the Pixels of the screen) 
margin-top:(half of the Pixels of the screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply apply the background and border to the .authform class or are you going for a different look?

```
.authform {
  padding: 15% 20px 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap for your inputs. Bootstrap's columns must be 12 in every row. In your case you have to add one div after every input.

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username"></label>  
<div class="col-md-4">
    <center><input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control input-md a-in" required="" type="text"></center>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

or

```
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="username"></label>  
<div class="col-md-6">
    <center><input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control input-md a-in" required="" type="text"></center>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```